# Volatile variables semantics

Tags: java, volatile

I have a few questions regarding volatile variables which are not long, double

1.is there a possibility of race condition when we write and read- meaning for example- while we read a volatile variable, someone can write a new value and the reading thread will not get the updated value?

2.can 2 writing threads write value and at the end, one of them will overlap the result of the other, also can a volatile be read with many threads at the same time meaning the reading threads overlap and all read the same result at the same time?

3.If we start 5 read and 5 write threads on 1 volatile variable, the result for the readers is unpredictable?

Comment: Also, read this: https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-jtp06197/

Comment: It sounds as if you're writing polling code. If you need to act on each change in a volatile variable, you'll need something better than that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Yes. You don't know which one happens first, so your reading thread sees one of two values.
2. If you mean overwrite, of course. If you have 2 writes then the last one wins. If you mean overlapping as in the resulting value becoming a combination of the two writes, then no. Not even with `long` and `double`.
3. Definitely. Unless you have for example `volatile int foo = 0;` and all the writers write `0`. Then you're guaranteed that all the readers will see `0`, otherwise it depends on scheduling and other such things.

All your questions look like you expect `volatile` to have something to do with *order*, but that's not true. It just guarantees *visibility*. If you want order, you'll have to enforce that yourself.

Comment: Thanks for the nice explanation and one more last question regarding question 1. so we are reading value and meantime someone sets a new value(let's say 10 ) we will read the last seen value by the last writer who ofcourse is not that one that just set 10?

Comment: There's no "same time". Either the reader reads the value before the writer writes it, or the writer writes the value and the reader reads it. Timing decides which one will happen.